# Scratch org is created without Alias and reports "Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined."

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

From one day to the other I am unable to create scratch orgs using the command which worked before:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f /Users/path/to/scratch-def.json -a MY_ORG -v DevHub -s -d 30
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined.

A scratch org gets created BUT it has not the alias `MY_ORG`, which make other scripts fail.

*This seems to be machine related as this works on other machines as before. My CLI is up-to-date and other commands work.*

Comment: Same for me as soon as I moved to the latest plugin version (sfdx-cli/6.36.0-391bf95737 - salesforcedx 44.3.0)

Comment: I tried several things, and installing the pre-release fixed the issue. So I assume it's a bug that's already known and will be fixed with the next version of the CLI. In the meantime you can try to install the pre-release version: sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release

Comment: Thanks Fabien. That indeed solved my problem. If you add it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done, cool to see it solved your issue too :)

Comment: This is usually a problem with the wrong dependencies getting installed somehow. The salesforce-alm module should be pointing to sfdx-core 0.23.1 where the problem is fixed. If you somehow have a previous version stuck in the modules, you will see this error. Can you try to uninstall pre-release and give the output of `sfdx plugins --core` ande look to see what your version of core you have in ~/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/@salesforce/sfdx-core/package.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has come up before when the `salesforcedx` plugin is relying on an updated version of `@salesforce/core` but, for some reason, there is an old version in the CLI node_modules.

Although installing `salesforcedx@pre-release` fixed this for you, that tag is no longer being updated now that v44 has moved to latest so you won't get any further updates. Instead, I would recommend updating to latest. `sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx` to remove your pre-release version, then `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx` (same as `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest`) to install off the latest tag. If you see the problem off latest, this would give us more information.

If you want to help us figure out why dependencies aren't getting updated, then you can uninstall pre-release, give the output for `sfdx plugins --core` and the contents of `~/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm/package.json`.

**Update:**

Based on the feedback, installing and uninstalling salesforcedx fixes the problem. It is usually best to keep salesforcedx so you get the updated one bundled with the CLI releases that are autoupdated. If anyone gets the error and wants to post the request information above, we can continue to debug the issue.

Comment: Great to see CLI devs here. I hope I am doing this right. I did `sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx` and here is what you asked for https://gist.github.com/rsoesemann/21df4261367c5937dddf60d888eb4085

Comment: And after calling `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest` I could create scratch orgs as before.

Comment: And here is mine: https://gist.github.com/FabienTaillon/d1b3028ea0854f1b8c4963c73569d156

Comment: Though after uninstalling the pre-release and before installing latest, I can create scratch org.

Comment: Ok thanks. The information you both sent looks fine. If any one is able to reproduce this again, try to send that information again. My guess is the core dependency in salesforce-alm will be a version before 0.20.0.

Answer (score 3):

I tried several things, and installing the pre-release fixed the issue. So I assume it's a bug that's already known and will be fixed with the next version of the CLI. In the meantime you can try to install the pre-release version: sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release.

Comment: I would prefer not to have this as the solution because you are just hiding the issue.

Comment: Just add a better answer. When it solves my problem without a prerelease CLI I will choose that one.

Comment: @Amphro I wanted to ping you, but it seems this was fix in the pre-release so didn’t want to ping you for nothing. Would be happy to have details on the issue + the fix. Real answer: just open source the CLI.

Comment: My point being, this is just masking the issue. As far as we know, this shouldn't be an issue and there is was nothing specific that fixed this in pre-release or latest. In fact, pre-release is *no longer* being updated until v45 get's moved over to pre-release. So my theory is some NPM module is getting munged. I'll put more details in an answer.

Comment: @Amphro: Is there any reason why the CLI can't be somewhat close-source but have a public issues page on Github?